# Multiple Foreach Loop - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to merge 2 foreach loop results into 1 table. Attached image.
[image]

**Column1 Products:**

```
$products=[{"product_name_id":"pro_des_5","quantity":180},{"product_name_id":"pro_des_6","quantity":240},{"product_name_id":"pro_des_7","quantity":156}];
```

**Rest data:**

```
$summary=[{"ptotal":1,"month":"March","product_id":"pro_des_7"},{"ptotal":3,"month":"April","product_id":"pro_des_5"},{"ptotal":2,"month":"April","product_id":"pro_des_6"},{"ptotal":12,"month":"April","product_id":"pro_des_7"}];
```

For each product there is per month consumption which I am trying to add under each month row getting data from $summary but unable to merge both foreach loop? Any advice.

```
<tbody>
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
<td>{{$product->product_name_id}}</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Array, have structure like this:

```
$array = [
   ["product_name_id" => "pro_des_5" , "jan" => 3, "feb" => 0 , ..etc ]
];
```

you will fill `$array` by looping throgh the `Column1 Products` and `Rest data` :

```
foreach($products as $product) {
  foreach($summary as $summary) {
     $value = 0;
    if ($summary->product_id == $product->product_name_id)
       // do the sum here also push to the new $array
       $value = ? // the sum you need
  }
  $array[] = ["product_name_id" => $product->product_name_id, $summary->month => $value ]
}
```

Then you can do like this :

```
<tbody>
@foreach($array as $product)
<tr>
<td>{{$product->product_name_id}}</td>
<td>{{$product->jan}}</td>
<td>{{$product->feb}}</td>
..
..
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: I am getting data from 2 different tables. $products & $summary are 2 different tables.

Comment: then you can have a relationship between two tables, so you can do something like this :  `$summary->product->quantity`

Comment: relationship how?

Comment: you can get the product information by the month, or the opposite

Comment: I like the idea of creating array, how I can do this? Just snippet will help me alot, thanks

Comment: Why $value? what I looking for each month and $summary is providing the data.

Comment: value can be `ptotal`. to be clear, value which will be print instead of zeros

Comment: Getting this result
[{"product_name_id":"pro_des_5","April":0},{"product_name_id":"pro_des_6","April":0},{"product_name_id":"pro_des_7","April":12}]